# number keeps resetting after view changes or app closes

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a score where after the user watches a rewarded video ad, the score will increase by 1. My code increases the score by 1 but after I change views and return back to the view that the score is shown, the score returns back to 0. How do I update the score?

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
class RewardedAdViewController: UIViewController, 
    GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scoreText: UILabel!

var score = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    //let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    //defaults.set(0, forKey: "score")

}



@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true{
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self )
    }
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {

    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self

}

func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {

    score = score + 1
    scoreText.text = String(score)
}
```

In the code above, I first declared `var score = 0` and then later in the code, when the user finishes watching the ad, it increases the score by 1

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {

    score = score + 1
    scoreText.text = String(score)
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It depends strongly on **how** to *change views and return back to the view that the score is shown*. If the instance of `RewardedAdViewController` is deallocated and recreated the behavior is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to store the score locally on the iPhone using NSUserDefaults, allowing the app to be closed and the value to remain saved on the system - [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

State like the `score` is only tracked as long as the object its declared-in stays in memory. When an object is created it gets memory assigned for its properties, when the object is no longer needed the memory is freed and all state is lost. In your example when the application is closed or the view is no longer shown on screen the object gets deallocated and the memory freed, the `score` does no longer exist.

To keep track of the `score` store it for example in the `NSUserDefaults` as p3t3r mentions.

Comment: Firstly, thank you to you and @p3t3r for your help. Would it be possible to elaborate on how to keep track of the `score` store it for example in the `NSUserDefaults`? I have first initialised `UserDefaults` using `let defaults = UserDefaults.standard`. Then wrote this code under `func rewardBasedVideoAd' I have added the following
        `defaults.set(0, forKey: "score")
        var score = defaults.integer(forKey: "score")
        score += 1
        scoreText.text = String(score)
    ` 

But it seems like I didn't fix it at all.

Comment: It needs to be stored in the UserDefaults after its incremented. Also always setting it to zero will reset the score every time...

Comment: What would be a possible solution to this problem? How would I store in the UserDefault after it has been incremented? Also I want it to start off as zero when the user first downloads the app. If I do not set it as zero then what should I do?

Comment: Setting a value in the UserDefaults stores the value. In viewDidLoad you want to read/ get the value from UserDefaults(the first time this will be nil or zero, see documentation). After incrementing you want to write/set the value in the UserDefaults(stores the value). This will store the score over app sessions. After deleting the app the UserDefaults also gets deleted.